# How to authenticate a username & password of the user without redirecting to another page?

Tags: php, javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I want to authenticate the user without refreshing/redirecting to another webpage. If the username and password combination is incorrect, I want to show a message there itself without redirecting/refreshing the page. And if the username and password combination is correct, then I want the page to redirect to home page. An example is given below, the error message appeared without refreshing the page. Can anyone help me in get this thing done? Thanks!

**Example**:

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far, take it you know its done with ajax otherwise you wouldn't of added the xmlhttprequest tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Ajax! the idea is to use `XmlHttpRequest` objects to send requests back to the server and get response .

**Google for PHP ajax login:**

1. http://www.roseindia.net/ajax/ajaxlogin/ajax-login-program.shtml
2. http://evolt.org/ajax_login_system

**Using jQuery:**

1. http://www.chazzuka.com/php-ajax-login-form-using-jquery-82/
2. http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/04/ajax-login-validation-php-jquery.html
3. http://ajaxmint.com/2009/12/php-ajax-login-form-using-jquery/

Comment: In the first link, OP used GET to send username and password which is not a proper way so, I would recommend sending username and password with POST so it is better to user jQuery `post()` ajax method. There is a slick documentation with nice sample codes: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the help of making ajax request to your php file, which will then execute your username and password and return true or fase or Other information about request.... 
This is the simplest way to do something on same page.

Comment: you got any link/material related to this?

Comment: @iSumitG: Why don't you google some sample codes on how to make Ajax request to PHP server.

Comment: @iSumitG, yes i understand your question. and there is a lot of free sample of this like.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two choices:

- **AJAX request** (as others suggest), that will submit the form and make proper action depending on whether this was success (eg. load private data) or error (eg. display information about incorrect username/password),
- **IFRAME containing login form**, that will reload itself, not the whole window (and eventually make some action or execute some script, depending on what you need),

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX! With it, user doesn't need to reload page to communicate with server.